# UseEndpoints routing to Login page with Identity on startup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Setting up a new solution with .net core 3.0 and trying to edit the startup to go to my area.

/Identity/Account/Login
Area : Identity
Controller : Account
View : Login

Tried :

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "/identity/account/login");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{area:identity}/{controller:account}/{action=login}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only authenticated user can access your application , you can provide a policy in the call to `AddAuthorization`.The `DefaultPolicy` is initially configured to require authentication, so no additional configuration is required :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
    });
}
```

MVC endpoints are marked as `RequireAuthorization` so that all requests must be authorized based on the DefaultPolicy. Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorization

So if not authenticated , user will be redirect to asp.net identity's login page .

Comment: This is awesome, thans you very much for your help.

Comment: If the reply helps, please consider mark as answer which may help others who meet same problem .